# Gitlab CI and PHPUnit Lumen - CI fails even though tests pass

Tags: php, phpunit, gitlab, lumen, gitlab-ci

For some reason, my Gitlab CI job that runs PHPUnit tests on a PHP Lumen application have just started failing- eventhough the tests are actually all passing.

Here is my YAML file:

```
    image: php:7.1.3

cache:
  paths:
  - vendor/

before_script:
- apt-get -qq update -y
- apt-get -qq install openssh-client -y
- apt-get -qq install git -y
- apt-get -qq install zip unzip
# setup the private key
- eval $(ssh-agent -s)
- ssh-add <(echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY")
- mkdir -p ~/.ssh
- echo -e "Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\n" > ~/.ssh/config
- ssh -L 3306:127.0.0.1:3306 XXX@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -Nf
- curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
- php composer.phar install

stages:
  - test


phpunit:
  stage: test
  script:
  - vendor/bin/phpunit --configuration phpunit.xml || exit 1
```

Here is the build log:

```
    [0KRunning with gitlab-ci-multi-runner 1.10.6 (2dadd48)[0;m
[0;m[0KUsing Docker executor with image php:7.1.3 ...
[0;m[0KPulling docker image php:7.1.3 ...
[0;mRunning on runner-2b6016b4-project-1032-concurrent-0 via xxx-iMac.local...
[32;1mFetching changes...[0;m
Removing composer.phar
Removing vendor/
HEAD is now at d08ea1a Restored CI yaml to how it was when it was passing, also changed some config attributes in phpunit xml file
From https://xxxxxxxxxx
   d08ea1a..bd0955d  development -> origin/development
[32;1mChecking out bd0955d0 as development...[0;m
[32;1mSkipping Git submodules setup[0;m
[32;1mChecking cache for phpunit/development...[0;m
[32;1mSuccessfully extracted cache[0;m
[32;1m$ apt-get -qq update -y[0;m
[32;1m$ apt-get -qq install openssh-client -y[0;m
debconf: delaying package configuration, since apt-utils is not installed
Selecting previously unselected package libxau6:amd64.
(Reading database ... 
(Reading database ... 5%
(Reading database ... 10%
(Reading database ... 15%
(Reading database ... 20%
(Reading database ... 25%
(Reading database ... 30%
(Reading database ... 35%
(Reading database ... 40%
(Reading database ... 45%
(Reading database ... 50%
(Reading database ... 55%
(Reading database ... 60%
(Reading database ... 65%
(Reading database ... 70%
(Reading database ... 75%
(Reading database ... 80%
(Reading database ... 85%
(Reading database ... 90%
(Reading database ... 95%
(Reading database ... 100%
(Reading database ... 12253 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libxau6_1%3a1.0.8-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libxau6:amd64 (1:1.0.8-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libxdmcp6:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libxdmcp6_1%3a1.1.1-1+b1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libxdmcp6:amd64 (1:1.1.1-1+b1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libxcb1:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libxcb1_1.10-3+b1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libxcb1:amd64 (1.10-3+b1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libx11-data.
Preparing to unpack .../libx11-data_2%3a1.6.2-3_all.deb ...
Unpacking libx11-data (2:1.6.2-3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libx11-6:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libx11-6_2%3a1.6.2-3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libx11-6:amd64 (2:1.6.2-3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libxext6:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libxext6_2%3a1.3.3-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libxext6:amd64 (2:1.3.3-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libxmuu1:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libxmuu1_2%3a1.1.2-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libxmuu1:amd64 (2:1.1.2-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package openssh-client.
Preparing to unpack .../openssh-client_1%3a6.7p1-5+deb8u3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking openssh-client (1:6.7p1-5+deb8u3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package xauth.
Preparing to unpack .../xauth_1%3a1.0.9-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking xauth (1:1.0.9-1) ...
Setting up libxau6:amd64 (1:1.0.8-1) ...
Setting up libxdmcp6:amd64 (1:1.1.1-1+b1) ...
Setting up libxcb1:amd64 (1.10-3+b1) ...
Setting up libx11-data (2:1.6.2-3) ...
Setting up libx11-6:amd64 (2:1.6.2-3) ...
Setting up libxext6:amd64 (2:1.3.3-1) ...
Setting up libxmuu1:amd64 (2:1.1.2-1) ...
Setting up openssh-client (1:6.7p1-5+deb8u3) ...
Setting up xauth (1:1.0.9-1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-18+deb8u7) ...
[32;1m$ apt-get -qq install git -y[0;m
debconf: delaying package configuration, since apt-utils is not installed
Selecting previously unselected package libpopt0:amd64.
(Reading database ... 
(Reading database ... 5%
(Reading database ... 10%
(Reading database ... 15%
(Reading database ... 20%
(Reading database ... 25%
(Reading database ... 30%
(Reading database ... 35%
(Reading database ... 40%
(Reading database ... 45%
(Reading database ... 50%
(Reading database ... 55%
(Reading database ... 60%
(Reading database ... 65%
(Reading database ... 70%
(Reading database ... 75%
(Reading database ... 80%
(Reading database ... 85%
(Reading database ... 90%
(Reading database ... 95%
(Reading database ... 100%
(Reading database ... 12600 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libpopt0_1.16-10_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpopt0:amd64 (1.16-10) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libcurl3-gnutls:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libcurl3-gnutls_7.38.0-4+deb8u5_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libcurl3-gnutls:amd64 (7.38.0-4+deb8u5) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libexpat1:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libexpat1_2.1.0-6+deb8u3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libexpat1:amd64 (2.1.0-6+deb8u3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package less.
Preparing to unpack .../archives/less_458-3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking less (458-3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package patch.
Preparing to unpack .../patch_2.7.5-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking patch (2.7.5-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package liberror-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../liberror-perl_0.17-1.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking liberror-perl (0.17-1.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package git-man.
Preparing to unpack .../git-man_1%3a2.1.4-2.1+deb8u2_all.deb ...
Unpacking git-man (1:2.1.4-2.1+deb8u2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package git.
Preparing to unpack .../git_1%3a2.1.4-2.1+deb8u2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking git (1:2.1.4-2.1+deb8u2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package rsync.
Preparing to unpack .../rsync_3.1.1-3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking rsync (3.1.1-3) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (215-17+deb8u6) ...
Setting up libpopt0:amd64 (1.16-10) ...
Setting up libcurl3-gnutls:amd64 (7.38.0-4+deb8u5) ...
Setting up libexpat1:amd64 (2.1.0-6+deb8u3) ...
Setting up less (458-3) ...
debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Dialog
debconf: (TERM is not set, so the dialog frontend is not usable.)
debconf: falling back to frontend: Readline
Setting up patch (2.7.5-1) ...
Setting up liberror-perl (0.17-1.1) ...
Setting up git-man (1:2.1.4-2.1+deb8u2) ...
Setting up git (1:2.1.4-2.1+deb8u2) ...
Setting up rsync (3.1.1-3) ...
invoke-rc.d: policy-rc.d denied execution of restart.
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-18+deb8u7) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (215-17+deb8u6) ...
[32;1m$ apt-get -qq install zip unzip[0;m
debconf: delaying package configuration, since apt-utils is not installed
Selecting previously unselected package unzip.
(Reading database ... 
(Reading database ... 5%
(Reading database ... 10%
(Reading database ... 15%
(Reading database ... 20%
(Reading database ... 25%
(Reading database ... 30%
(Reading database ... 35%
(Reading database ... 40%
(Reading database ... 45%
(Reading database ... 50%
(Reading database ... 55%
(Reading database ... 60%
(Reading database ... 65%
(Reading database ... 70%
(Reading database ... 75%
(Reading database ... 80%
(Reading database ... 85%
(Reading database ... 90%
(Reading database ... 95%
(Reading database ... 100%
(Reading database ... 13497 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../unzip_6.0-16+deb8u2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking unzip (6.0-16+deb8u2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package zip.
Preparing to unpack .../archives/zip_3.0-8_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking zip (3.0-8) ...
Setting up unzip (6.0-16+deb8u2) ...
Setting up zip (3.0-8) ...
[32;1m$ eval $(ssh-agent -s)[0;m
Agent pid 377
[32;1m$ ssh-add <(echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY")[0;m
Identity added: /dev/fd/63 (rsa w/o comment)
[32;1m$ mkdir -p ~/.ssh[0;m
[32;1m$ echo -e "Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\n" > ~/.ssh/config[0;m
[32;1m$ ssh -L 3306:127.0.0.1:3306 xx@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -Nf[0;m
Warning: Permanently added '128.243.22.101' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
[32;1m$ curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php[0;m
All settings correct for using Composer
Downloading...

Composer (version 1.4.1) successfully installed to: /builds/XXXXX/XXXX/composer.phar
Use it: php composer.phar

[32;1m$ php composer.phar install[0;m
Do not run Composer as root/super user! See https://getcomposer.org/root for details
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Package operations: 3 installs, 38 updates, 1 removal
  - Removing symfony/yaml (v3.2.6)
  - Updating symfony/debug (v3.2.6 => v3.2.7): Downloading (connecting...)Downloading (0%)           Downloading (5%)Downloading (15%)Downloading (20%)Downloading (25%)Downloading (35%)Downloading (40%)Downloading (55%)Downloading (60%)Downloading (75%)Downloading (80%)Downloading (100%)
  - Updating symfony/console (v3.2.6 => v3.2.7): Downloading (connecting...)Downloading (0%)           Downloading (5%)Downloading (10%)Downloading (15%)Downloading (20%)Downloading (25%)Downloading (30%)Downloading (35%)Downloading (40%)Downloading (45%)Downloading (50%)Downloading (55%)Downloading (60%)Downloading (65%)Downloading (70%)Downloading (75%)Downloading (80%)Downloading (85%)Downloading (90%)Downloading (95%)Downloading (100%)
  - Updating symfony/translation (v3.2.6 => v3.2.7): Downloading (connecting...)Downloading (0%)           Downloading (5%)Downloading (10%)Downloading (15%)Downloading (20%)Downloading (25%)Downloading (30%)Downloading (35%)Downloading (40%)Downloading (45%)Downloading (50%)Downloading (55%)Downloading (60%)Downloading (65%)Downloading (70%)Downloading (75%)Downloading (80%)Downloading (90%)Downloading (100%)
  - Updating illuminate/contracts (v5.4.13 => v5.4.17): Downloading (connecting...)Downloading (0%)           Downloading (15%)Downloading (25%)Downloading (40%)Downloading (50%)Downloading (60%)Downloading (75%)Downloading (90%)Downloading (100%)
  - Updating illuminate/support (v5.4.13 => v5.4.17): Downloading (connecting...)Downloading (0%)           Downloading (5%)Downloading (10%)Downloading (15%)Downloading (50%)Downloading (55%)Downloading (60%)Downloading (80%)Downloading (85%)Downloading (90%)Downloading (95%)Downloading (100%)
  - Updating illuminate/console (v5.4.13 => v5.4.17): Downloading (connecting...)Downloading (0%)           Downloading (20%)Downloading (40%)Downloading (95%)Downloading (100%)
  - Updating symfony/http-foundation (v3.2.6 => v3.2.7): Downloading (connecting...)Downloading (0%)           Downloading (5%)Downloading (10%)Downloading (15%)Downloading (20%)Downloading (25%)Downloading (30%)Downloading (35%)Downloading (40%)Downloading (45%)Downloading (50%)Downloading (55%)Downloading (60%)Downloading (65%)Downloading (70%)Downloading (75%)Downloading (80%)Downloading (85%)Downloading (90%)Downloading (95%)Downloading (100%)
  - Updating symfony/finder (v3.2.6 => v3.2.7): Downloading (connecting...)Downloading (0%)           Downloading (5%)Downloading (10%)Downloading (15%)Downloading (20%)Downloading (25%)Downloading (35%)Downloading (40%)Downloading (45%)Downloading (80%)Downloading (85%)Downloading (90%)Downloading (95%)Downloading (100%)
  - Updating illuminate/filesystem (v5.4.13 => v5.4.17): Downloading (connecting...)Downloading (0%)           Downloading (85%)Downloading (95%)Downloading (100%)
  - Updating illuminate/session (v5.4.13 => v5.4.17): Downloading (connecting...)Downloading (0%)           Downloading (45%)Downloading (60%)Downloading (95%)Downloading (100%)
  - Updating symfony/event-dispatcher (v3.2.6 => v3.2.7): Downloading (connecting...)Downloading (0%)           Downloading (5%)Downloading (10%)Downloading (15%)Downloading (65%)Downloading (70%)Downloading (75%)Downloading (80%)Downloading (100%)
  - Updating symfony/http-kernel (v3.2.6 => v3.2.7): Downloading (connecting...)Downloading (0%)           Downloading (5%)Downloading (10%)Downloading (15%)Downloading (20%)Downloading (25%)Downloading (30%)Downloading (35%)Downloading (40%)Downloading (45%)Downloading (50%)Downloading (55%)Downloading (60%)Downloading (65%)Downloading (70%)Downloading (75%)Downloading (80%)Downloading (85%)Downloading (90%)Downloading (95%)Downloading (100%)
  - Updating illuminate/container (v5.4.13 => v5.4.17): Downloading (connecting...)Downloading (0%)           Downloading (15%)Downloading (30%)Downloading (45%)Downloading (60%)Downloading (75%)Downloading (90%)Downloading (100%)
  - Updating illuminate/events (v5.4.13 => v5.4.17): Downloading (connecting...)Downloading (0%)           Downloading (100%)
  - Updating illuminate/view (v5.4.13 => v5.4.17): Downloading (connecting...)Downloading (0%)           Downloading (30%)Downloading (55%)Downloading (65%)Downloading (70%)Downloading (85%)Downloading (90%)Downloading (100%)
  - Updating illuminate/translation (v5.4.13 => v5.4.17): Downloading (connecting...)Downloading (0%)           Downloading (50%)Downloading (100%)
  - Updating illuminate/validation (v5.4.13 => v5.4.17): Downloading (connecting...)Downloading (0%)           Downloading (40%)Downloading (60%)Downloading (65%)Downloading (95%)Downloading (100%)
  - Updating symfony/process (v3.2.6 => v3.2.7): Downloading (connecting...)Downloading (0%)           Downloading (25%)Downloading (50%)Downloading (60%)Downloading (75%)Downloading (80%)Downloading (85%)Downloading (100%)
  - Updating illuminate/queue (v5.4.13 => v5.4.17): Downloading (connecting...)Downloading (0%)           Downloading (5%)Downloading (10%)Downloading (15%)Downloading (35%)Downloading (40%)Downloading (45%)Downloading (50%)Downloading (55%)Downloading (60%)Downloading (100%)
  - Updating illuminate/pipeline (v5.4.13 => v5.4.17): Downloading (connecting...)Downloading (0%)           Downloading (40%)Downloading (100%)
  - Updating illuminate/pagination (v5.4.13 => v5.4.17): Downloading (connecting...)Downloading (0%)           Downloading (25%)Downloading (50%)Downloading (100%)
  - Updating illuminate/http (v5.4.13 => v5.4.17): Downloading (connecting...)Downloading (0%)           Downloading (50%)Downloading (55%)Downloading (85%)Downloading (90%)Downloading (100%)
  - Updating illuminate/hashing (v5.4.13 => v5.4.17): Downloading (connecting...)Downloading (0%)           Downloading (100%)
  - Updating illuminate/encryption (v5.4.13 => v5.4.17): Downloading (connecting...)Downloading (0%)           Downloading (100%)
  - Updating illuminate/database (v5.4.13 => v5.4.17): Downloading (connecting...)Downloading (0%)           Downloading (5%)Downloading (10%)Downloading (15%)Downloading (20%)Downloading (25%)Downloading (30%)Downloading (35%)Downloading (40%)Downloading (45%)Downloading (50%)Downloading (55%)Downloading (60%)Downloading (65%)Downloading (70%)Downloading (75%)Downloading (80%)Downloading (85%)Downloading (90%)Downloading (95%)Downloading (100%)
  - Updating illuminate/config (v5.4.13 => v5.4.17): Downloading (connecting...)Downloading (0%)           Downloading (100%)
  - Updating illuminate/cache (v5.4.13 => v5.4.17): Downloading (connecting...)Downloading (0%)           Downloading (5%)Downloading (10%)Downloading (100%)
  - Updating illuminate/bus (v5.4.13 => v5.4.17): Downloading (connecting...)Downloading (0%)           Downloading (100%)
  - Updating illuminate/broadcasting (v5.4.13 => v5.4.17): Downloading (connecting...)Downloading (0%)           Downloading (55%)Downloading (85%)Downloading (100%)
  - Updating illuminate/auth (v5.4.13 => v5.4.17): Downloading (connecting...)Downloading (0%)           Downloading (10%)Downloading (20%)Downloading (50%)Downloading (60%)Downloading (65%)Downloading (75%)Downloading (85%)Downloading (90%)Downloading (100%)
  - Updating laravel/lumen-framework (v5.4.5 => v5.4.6): Downloading (connecting...)Downloading (0%)           Downloading (5%)Downloading (30%)Downloading (35%)Downloading (50%)Downloading (55%)Downloading (80%)Downloading (85%)Downloading (100%)
  - Updating sebastian/recursion-context (2.0.0 => 3.0.0): Downloading (connecting...)Downloading (0%)           Downloading (35%)Downloading (70%)Downloading (100%)
  - Installing sebastian/object-reflector (1.1.1): Downloading (connecting...)Downloading (0%)           Downloading (65%)Downloading (100%)
  - Updating sebastian/object-enumerator (2.0.1 => 3.0.2): Downloading (connecting...)Downloading (0%)           Downloading (100%)
  - Updating sebastian/exporter (2.0.0 => 3.1.0): Downloading (connecting...)Downloading (0%)           Downloading (100%)
  - Updating sebastian/comparator (1.2.4 => 2.0.0): Downloading (connecting...)Downloading (0%)           Downloading (35%)Downloading (45%)Downloading (55%)Downloading (80%)Downloading (95%)Downloading (100%)
  - Updating phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects (3.4.3 => 4.0.1): Downloading (connecting...)Downloading (0%)           Downloading (5%)Downloading (15%)Downloading (20%)Downloading (25%)Downloading (35%)Downloading (40%)Downloading (45%)Downloading (50%)Downloading (55%)Downloading (60%)Downloading (65%)Downloading (75%)Downloading (80%)Downloading (85%)Downloading (95%)Downloading (100%)
  - Updating phpunit/php-code-coverage (4.0.8 => 5.1.0): Downloading (connecting...)Downloading (0%)           Downloading (5%)Downloading (10%)Downloading (15%)Downloading (20%)Downloading (25%)Downloading (30%)Downloading (35%)Downloading (40%)Downloading (45%)Downloading (50%)Downloading (55%)Downloading (60%)Downloading (65%)Downloading (75%)Downloading (80%)Downloading (90%)Downloading (95%)Downloading (100%)
  - Installing phar-io/version (1.0.1): Downloading (connecting...)Downloading (0%)           Downloading (50%)Downloading (55%)Downloading (100%)
  - Installing phar-io/manifest (1.0.1): Downloading (connecting...)Downloading (0%)           Downloading (10%)Downloading (20%)Downloading (30%)Downloading (45%)Downloading (60%)Downloading (70%)Downloading (85%)Downloading (90%)Downloading (100%)
  - Updating phpunit/phpunit (5.7.18 => 6.1.0): Downloading (connecting...)Downloading (0%)           Downloading (5%)Downloading (10%)Downloading (15%)Downloading (20%)Downloading (25%)Downloading (30%)Downloading (35%)Downloading (40%)Downloading (45%)Downloading (50%)Downloading (55%)Downloading (60%)Downloading (65%)Downloading (80%)Downloading (85%)Downloading (90%)Downloading (95%)Downloading (100%)
Generating autoload files
[32;1m$ vendor/bin/phpunit --configuration phpunit.xml[0;m
PHPUnit 6.1.0 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

........................W......................................  63 / 224 ( 28%)
..................................................W............ 126 / 224 ( 56%)
WW............................................................. 189 / 224 ( 84%)
...............WW..................                             224 / 224 (100%)

Time: 24.6 seconds, Memory: 38.00MB

There were 6 warnings:

1) Warning
No tests found in class "XX".

2) Warning
No tests found in class "XX".

3) Warning
No tests found in class "XX".

4) Warning
No tests found in class "XX".

5) Warning
No tests found in class "XX".

6) Warning
No tests found in class "XX".

WARNINGS!
Tests: 224, Assertions: 218, Warnings: 6.
[31;1mERROR: Build failed: exit code 1
[0;m
```

Like I say, these tests are actually passing and weren't failing the CI just a few days ago.

Can anyone advise?

Gitlab Version: GitLab Community Edition 8.17.0 77254ab
CI runner using Docker (latest version to date)

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the files you marked with `XX`? It seems they do not contain any tests or do not adhere to the conventions for phpunit, i.e. tests must be prefix with `test`. If you have files in your tests folder that do not contain tests you might want to fix them or throw them away.

I created an example to demonstrate the issue:

```
<?php

require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

class Question43423064Test extends TestCase
{
    //function testTrue() { $this->assertTrue(true); }
}
```

When running that test I get a similar output as you:

```
dbr:stackoverflow/ $ phpunit Question43423064Test.php 
PHPUnit 6.0.6 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

W                                                                   1 / 1 (100%)

Time: 64 ms, Memory: 8.00MB

There was 1 warning:

1) Warning
No tests found in class "Question43423064Test".

WARNINGS!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 0, Warnings: 1.

dbr:stackoverflow/ $ echo $?
1
```

The `echo $?` will print the last return code and as you can see it's 1. If you remove the comment or add a skipped annotation, the warning will go away and the exit code should be back to 0.

tl;dr It looks like you either have to throw out these files, fix the included tests or maybe mark them as skipped if you want to fix them later.

Comment: Do warnings cause phpunit to return a value not equal to zero? Most testing tools will only return non-zero error codes if there are errors.

Comment: Yes it does, at least on my machine. You can try `echo $?` after running phpunit in your CLI and it will return the last returned status code, which is 1. Judging from the output you provided it returns the same status code in your CI-environment.

Comment: Ok, then you're probably right, the warnings are causing the issue. The job is failing because the tests are failing.

Comment: PhpUnit will return success when there are no tests as well. In this case it warns about test files where there are no tests specified. Since it's likely an issue (because why would you need an empty test file) PhpUnit warns about it and it treats it as an unsuccessful run. As mentioned in my answer, since those files are not run anyway you can safely remove them or if they actually contain tests you might want to find out why they are not recognized by PhpUnit.

Comment: Hi. The only reason why I have empty files is because the system is being developed still, and as my team builds it, test files will be empty.

I just find it strange that the warnings (no assertions are failing I might add) are suddenly causing the builds to fail. As a workaround, i've just added an assertTrue(true, true) test into those empty files and have instructed my team to remove those as they begin work in that file, hardly ideal I know.

Comment: Instead of asserting true=true, you could also create empty methods that describe what needs to be tested, e.g. `testSomeMethodReturnsSomeObject` and then instead of adding an empty assert, mark the test as incomplete: `$this->markTestIncomplete('some message');`

Answer (score 0):

```
script:
  - vendor/bin/phpunit --configuration phpunit.xml || exit 1
```

you use `exit 1` - an exit >0 is always threaded like an error.

use `exit 0` or `true`

see http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exit.3.html

as long as you dont call phpunit with `--fail-on-warning` it shouldnt use an exit code >0